# Can I use a member function type predicate as a predicate to filter()?

Tags: typescript

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
class Thing {
  name?: string;
  color?: string;
  notes?: string;

  constructor(public id: string) {}

  isDisplayable(): this is DisplayableThing {
    return this.name !== undefined && this.color !== undefined;
  }
}

interface DisplayableThing extends Thing {
  name: string;
  color: string;
}

const things: Thing[] = [];
const displayableThings = things.filter<DisplayableThing>((thing) => thing.isDisplayable());
```

[See on the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqAWBLAdgc2gbwFDWssAtgKYD8AXNBAC4BOKqA3DtMAPYis3mW31O7JWVIhG7U6aJszbJxAV2BVOACgAOcgEYhEwaIgAmFcfQCUmAL5ZmiCABEbq8AE8wWospMUqSGDej2IRzAXNwR6TGZcGiIqORpkaG8bADp8YmgAQgBeLOg5ZH0iADMUIn1oADIKxJ9ktg4aTJy8guLS-X5oS0ssFGEaIrBgIn8HZ1cQIjC0aCIAD2ECmGn0bAFCIiNeSWl2Ti2JRiwemWoa+ggKFYBtAF1oXLumU6pofTHgiamkNBhcpN+yRKIH6AB4AkEQpMVgA+ZTKAGoMxZGHnNDJGwQ8ZuDwmJhAA)

The background to this is that I have several sources of data about `Thing` objects, which arrive via `EventSource` streams.  One event tells me the color of a `Thing`, another event tells me about the name of a `Thing` and another provides some notes about a `Thing`.  I can't sensibly display a `Thing` until I have both a name and a colour.  Once I have both, I'd like to be able to just get all the displayable ones and then treat them as `DisplayableThing` instances because now I know that `name` and `color` are defined (but `notes` still might not be).  But the event with the notes might arrive first, in which case I have to note that the `Thing` exists while not having enough information to display it.

Ideally, I could just `things.filter<DisplayableThing>((thing) => thing.isDisplayable())` but it seems I need an extra type annotation that's largely redundant.  If that's just the way it is and I have to point out to TypeScript that `thing.isDisplayable()` returns `thing is DisplayableThing` even though that's already the type of that function then fine, but I was wondering if there's a sensible way of doing this that avoids the repetition.

Comment: `Shape.prototype.isCircle({ shapeType: "circle" })` is _false_.

Comment: @jonrsharpe or even a TypeError in strict mode, since the invocation will have `this = undefined`.

Comment: "*It looks like shapes.filter<Circle>((shape) => shape.isCircle()) should work, but somehow the return type this is Circle of isCircle() is being lost*" well, custom type guards simply aren't transitive. I know this is a contrived example but I'd heavily advise against it. 1. You don't want to have logic like this in the class anyway. The `area()` method is a clear code smell - adding a new shape means the `area` needs to be changed as well. This can be polymorphic. But to have a clearly reusable predicate, make it a function. In OO it'd be a utility class but that's just functions.

Comment: Or, if you prefer no alternative ways to express this, you can just annotate your callback: `shapes.filter<Circle>((shape): shape is Circle => shape.isCircle())`

Comment: @VLAZ I'll rework this with a better example of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Tom It's clear to me what you try to do. Just not why you think that's the way to go. Separate function (or even method) that *accepts* an object as parameter and acts as a custom type guard would 1. play nicer with the type system 2. play nicer by just pure software design. And if you really, really, *really* need to use a method that type-guards based on `this`, you can still wrap it in a custom type guard callback as I've shown. Trying to pass around a this-based guard is just going to involve jumping through hoops. It's not even reusable even if we ignore the type system.

Comment: @VLAZ well I hope the reworked question shows better why I'm trying to do it.  It doesn't seem to me an unreasonable thing to do.  If the answer is just, "You can't do that" then fine.

Comment: @Tom I edited to make the question more concise and dropped the old version. I don't think it's needed, the new one is clearer and more to the point.

Comment: I don't think it's an *answer* to your question, so I'll just comment: A static predicate seems like a nice concise, scoped approach: `const displayableThings = things.filter(Thing.isDisplayable);` [playground](https://tsplay.dev/N9anVN) It will still have access to `Thing` internals, but can be used directly in the `filter`, avoiding issues with `this`.

Comment: Just to note also that there is a [PR in progress](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/57465) to make the untyped predicate correctly infer its return type as a type predicate rather than collapsing to `boolean`.  With this in place, `things.filter<DisplayableThing>((thing) => this.isDisplayable())` will behave as expected.